Multiple Payment Intents for one available item | stripe
I am experiencing what could be called a classical system design problem: In my e-commerce flow I have only one item and multiple users that want to buy this item. This means that multiple PaymentIntents are created, however only the first fastest user to pay will get the item. However, all other users eventually still make a payment for it and at that moment in time there is no item left to buy.
The problem is that the quantity of an item is only lowered upon PaymentIntentSucceeded event. However, if the quantity would be lowered upon PaymentIntent creation, then there would need to be some kind of logic to handle hanging PaymentIntents (stale payments where a user initiates a payment but never pays).
What would be the solution to this problem?

Generally you would track your inventory and when the payment session begins you set aside that inventory and then have a "cart timeout" where you release that inventory after a designated period of time and invalidate the session (you could cancel the PaymentIntent at this point).

How would you invoke the cancellation call after the timeout has passed?
